# enter special (CR and single quote) characters into SQLite Database

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to add a couple of rows to my sqlite database to 'initialize' it. I need to add a column with single quotes and a carriage return. The CR needs to be before the first single quote. The code below enters the data on one line and has double quotes.

```
$commonName = sqlite_escape_string("Blanket Flower 'Fanfare'");

try{
    $query = "INSERT INTO plant(id,
                            common_Name, 
                            latin_Name) 
              VALUES (1,:commonname,'Gaillardia')";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);

    $statement->bindParam(':commonname', $commonName);
    $statement->execute();
```

I appreciate your time,
Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `bindParam`, there is no need to use `sqlite_escape_string`.

```
$commonName = "Blanket Flower\n'Fanfare'";
```